# How do you set the color of a Google calendar event using the API

Tags: api, google-calendar-api

This question has been asked a while ago but has not been answered. I think things have moved on since.

I can create an event using the API but I am unable to set the colour to anything other than the default. This is :colorId is not working? Any ideas?

```
    event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
                                                    :summary => @measure.value,

                                                    :description => 'created by ' + current_user.username,
                                                    :start => {
                                                        :date_time => event_starttime
                                                    },
                                                    :end => {
                                                        :date_time => event_endtime
                                                    },
                                                    :colorId => "6"
                                                })
```

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this because I was having the same problem. I'm using the ruby api client and I dug into its [code](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/calendar_v3/classes.rb) to find this:

```
# The color of the event. This is an ID referring to an entry in the event
# section of the colors definition (see the  colors endpoint). Optional.
# Corresponds to the JSON property `colorId`
# @return [String]
attr_accessor :color_id
```

Updating my event insert call to use `color_id: 'a number from 1 to 11'` worked for me.

Comment: I'm using the JAVA API to update event colors - it works fine to set specific colors, but how do you update an event to use the default calendar colour? Setting colorId to null has no effect, despite that being the colorId value for events with the default color. I can update with the current default color... but I want the event to revert to using the default color, whatever that may be in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [@CChandler81](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136330/cchandler81) answer, an event's color is set using a colorId; an integer value from 1 to 11.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSMrI.png) shows 11 events using the 11 colors.

The events were created using the following Python code:

```
colorId = 1
for day in range(4):
    event_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=day)
    event_date_str = event_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    for start_hour in range(0,12,4):
        start_time = datetime.time(hour=start_hour)
        end_time = datetime.time(hour=start_hour + 4)
        # Create calendar event specifying colorId
        event = {
            'summary': f'colorId {colorId}',
            'colorId': colorId,
            'start': {
                'dateTime': f"{event_date_str}{start_time.strftime('T%H:%M:%S')}",
                'timeZone': 'Europe/London',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': f"{event_date_str}{end_time.strftime('T%H:%M:%S')}",
                'timeZone': 'Europe/London',
            }
        }
        service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
        # Prepare for next event or finish if all colors used
        colorId += 1
        if colorId > 11:
            break
```

The above was added into the quickstart example from the Google Calendar API [Python Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python). A useful example of getting color information, in various languages, is available at [Colors: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get).

Updating the Python example:

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
colors = service.colors().get().execute()
for key, value in colors.items():
    print(f'color key \'{key}\': {value}')

for item in ['calendar', 'event']:
    print(f'Colors {item}:')
    for colorId, color in colors[item].items():
        back = color['background']
        fore = color['foreground']
        print(f'colorId \'{colorId}\': Background={back}, foreground={fore}')
```

Slotting above into the same quickstart example outputs:

```
color key 'kind': calendar#colors
color key 'updated': 2012-02-14T00:00:00.000Z
color key 'calendar': {'1': {'background': '#ac725e', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '2': {'background': '#d06b64', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '3': {'background': '#f83a22', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '4': {'background': '#fa573c', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '5': {'background': '#ff7537', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '6': {'background': '#ffad46', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '7': {'background': '#42d692', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '8': {'background': '#16a765', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '9': {'background': '#7bd148', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '10': {'background': '#b3dc6c', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '11': {'background': '#fbe983', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '12': {'background': '#fad165', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '13': {'background': '#92e1c0', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '14': {'background': '#9fe1e7', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '15': {'background': '#9fc6e7', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '16': {'background': '#4986e7', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '17': {'background': '#9a9cff', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '18': {'background': '#b99aff', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '19': {'background': '#c2c2c2', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '20': {'background': '#cabdbf', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '21': {'background': '#cca6ac', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '22': {'background': '#f691b2', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '23': {'background': '#cd74e6', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '24': {'background': '#a47ae2', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}}
color key 'event': {'1': {'background': '#a4bdfc', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '2': {'background': '#7ae7bf', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '3': {'background': '#dbadff', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '4': {'background': '#ff887c', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '5': {'background': '#fbd75b', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '6': {'background': '#ffb878', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '7': {'background': '#46d6db', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '8': {'background': '#e1e1e1', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '9': {'background': '#5484ed', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '10': {'background': '#51b749', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}, '11': {'background': '#dc2127', 'foreground': '#1d1d1d'}}
Colors calendar:
colorId '1': Background=#ac725e, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '2': Background=#d06b64, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '3': Background=#f83a22, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '4': Background=#fa573c, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '5': Background=#ff7537, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '6': Background=#ffad46, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '7': Background=#42d692, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '8': Background=#16a765, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '9': Background=#7bd148, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '10': Background=#b3dc6c, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '11': Background=#fbe983, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '12': Background=#fad165, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '13': Background=#92e1c0, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '14': Background=#9fe1e7, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '15': Background=#9fc6e7, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '16': Background=#4986e7, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '17': Background=#9a9cff, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '18': Background=#b99aff, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '19': Background=#c2c2c2, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '20': Background=#cabdbf, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '21': Background=#cca6ac, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '22': Background=#f691b2, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '23': Background=#cd74e6, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '24': Background=#a47ae2, foreground=#1d1d1d
Colors event:
colorId '1': Background=#a4bdfc, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '2': Background=#7ae7bf, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '3': Background=#dbadff, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '4': Background=#ff887c, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '5': Background=#fbd75b, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '6': Background=#ffb878, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '7': Background=#46d6db, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '8': Background=#e1e1e1, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '9': Background=#5484ed, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '10': Background=#51b749, foreground=#1d1d1d
colorId '11': Background=#dc2127, foreground=#1d1d1d
```

Answer (score 0):

In creating calendar events using [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), there's an optional property called `colorId`

> **colorId**   string  The color of the event. This is an ID referring to an
>   entry in the event section of the colors definition (see the colors
>   endpoint). Optional.  writable

Check the [Colors property resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors) on format for setting background and foreground colors.